# How to calculate the percentage of rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, percentage

I would like to create a new row consisting of the percentage of the each column's ones and minus ones.

```
alldata_2.head()

Conditions          -1       1
NormalBlink1400     48      108
NormalBlink2000     74      124
NormalBlink3000     77      147
NormalBlink4000     67      150
NormalNoBlink1400   40      119
```

the two rows I want to add: perc_one = (one / one + minus_one)
                            perc_minus_one = (minus_one / one + minus_one)

Comment: Can you please give expected output for the above dataframe?

Comment: [How to create new columns from existing columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html) ... [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) .. [pandas.DataFrame.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) - along axis 1.

Comment: Can you make the representation of the dataframe? And clarify what the example of the output you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Conditions ': ['NormalBlink1400', 'NormalBlink2000', 'NormalBlink3000', 'NormalBlink4000','NormalNoBlink1400'], 
        '-1': [48, 74, 77, 67,40], 
        '1': [108, 124, 147, 150,119]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df['perc_one '] = (df["1"] / (df["1"] + df["-1"]))
df["perc_minus_one"] = (df["-1"] / (df["1"] + df["-1"]))
```

Output:

```
df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I would expect but the user states they would like extra rows not extra columns - needs clarity